# Как создать бд в postgresql используя bash скрипт

Tags: postgresql, bash

По сути вопрос сводится к тому как выполнить:
`CREATE DATABASE test_db;`
из `bash` не коннектясь в консоль `psql`

Comment: ну совсем не коннектясь не выйдет, просто команды можно подавать не с консоли, а на стандартный ввод: `echo "create  database ..." | psql ...`

Answer (score 1):

Держите, переменная PGPASSWORD нужна на случай если у Вас доступ по паролю

```
#!/bin/bash
export PGPASSWORD="passs"



test=$(psql -h localhost -t -U username  -c  "CREATE DATABSE test.db")
echo $test
```